# C++ thread: can lock_guard own a mutex that owned by a unique_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In the example code [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), it shows that:

After `worker` thread owns the mutex (unique lock), and then wait.

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
cv.wait(lk, []{return ready;});
```

The `main` thread can still get the mutex (lock guard).

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
    ready = true;
}
```

Does this mean that lock_guard can own a mutex that owned by a unique_lock ?

Comment: No.  The documentation clearly stats that `condition_variable::wait` releases the lock.  It says that clearly in your linked documentation.  See:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait

Answer (score 2):

No, it means that during the `wait` the mutex is unlocked to allow provider threads to lock it and have authority over the cv. You omitted the most significant line in the example code you're referring to, the `notify_one`:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
    ready = true;
    std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
}
cv.notify_one(); // wake up the waiting thread
```

That's why you need to supply the lock to `wait`, so it can unlock it before the sleep and attempt to relock it after it has woken up.

From the first section of the page you linked, especially note 2 and 3:

> Any thread that intends to wait on std::condition_variable has to
>
> 1. acquire a std::unique_lock, on the same mutex as used to protect the shared variable
> 2. execute wait, wait_for, or wait_until. The wait operations atomically release the mutex and suspend the execution of the thread.
> 3. When the condition variable is notified, a timeout expires, or a spurious wakeup occurs, the thread is awakened, and the mutex is atomically reacquired. The thread should then check the condition and resume waiting if the wake up was spurious.