# Preventing concurrent read/write to class-member

Tags: c++, multithreading

Searched but could not find clarity, so here's my problem:
Need to update & read a member from different threads, something like the following:

```
template<typename T> struct State
{
    std::map<std::string, T> statedata;
    static std::mutex mux_state;
    ...
    void update(std::string k, T t)
    {
        while (!mux_state.try_lock()) timeoutdelay(TOD_UPDATE);
        ..do update..
        mux_state.unlock();
    }
    ...
    T read(std::string k)
    {
        while (!mux_state.try_lock()) timeoutdelay(TOD_READ);
        T t=statedata[k];
        mux_state.unlock();
        return t;
    }
    ...
}
...
State<mytype> state;
...
..from thread_1() randomly
    state.update(..)
...
..from thread_2() randomly
    state.read(..)
```

The need is for the update() & read() calls to always have exclusive access. 
Does my scheme above enable that, or is there a better/correct way of doing it?

`timeoutdelay()` hides aborting conditions so that the calling thread is not blocked indefinitely.

Comment: You never should `lock()` / `unlock()` mutexes manually, this is highly dangerous. Use a `std::lock_guard` instead.

Comment: Why is the mutex `static` ? This will cause objects to interfere with each other, degrading overall performance. Coarse-grained locks can rapidly cause a multi-threaded program to perform worse than a single-threaded one.

Comment: @MSalters: you have a point there, I guess the template<> blind-sided me

Comment: @slashmais https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315967/c-thread-can-lock-guard-own-a-mutex-that-owned-by-a-unique-lock

Comment: @slashmais _"timeoutdelay() hides aborting conditions so that the calling thread is not blocked indefinitely"_ That's an indicator you should rethink your overall design here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yes, that's why this question

Comment: @slashmais So if your thread needs to do additional things besides accessing the stuff within `timeoutdelay()` this should be probably factored out to a different thread running periodically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `while` loops with [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard). Such busy loops are blocking the calling thread until the lock is obtained, so just let the guard do the blocking for you. Don't lock/unlock a `std::mutex` manually, let the guard do it:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct State
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, T> statedata;
    std::mutex mux_state;

public:
    ...
    void update(std::string k, T t)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mux_state);
        statedata[k] = std::move(t);
    }
    ...
    T read(std::string k)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(mux_state);
        return statedata[k];
    }
    ...
};
```

**UPDATE**: if you really need a timeout while waiting for the mutex lock to be obtained so you can do other things, you can use a [`std::timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex) for that:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct State
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, T> statedata;
    std::timed_mutex mux_state;

public:
    ...
    bool update(std::string k, T t)
    {
        while (!mux_state.try_wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(TOD_UPDATE))) {
            if (check_abort_conditions())
                return false;
        }
        statedata[k] = std::move(t);
        return true;
    }
    ...
    bool read(std::string k, T &value)
    {
        while (!mux_state.try_wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(TOD_UPDATE))) {
            if (check_abort_conditions())
                return false;
        }
        value = statedata[k];
        return true;
    }
    ...
};
```

Using `std::mutex::try_lock()` (or `std::timed_mutex::try_lock()`) returns immediately, which may not allow the calling thread to yield to other threads when used in a busy loop.  Using `std::timed_mutex::try_wait_for()` puts the calling thread to sleep until the timeout elapses, allowing other threads to run.

Comment: Remy, apologies, I edited a clarification to my question: that the timeoutdelay() may cause early abort of the update() (or read()) methods so that the calling thread can continue (I should have added it from the start, sorry about that)

Comment: "If you can't beat 'em, join 'em!" - :^ thank you for your trouble